# Error creating github repo using terraform

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-provider-github

Receiving below error while trying to create a github repo using terraform
Error below. Can some help help me to understand what am i missing here?

```
Error: POST https://api.github.com/repos/github/terraform-module-template/generate: 404 Not Found []
```

My script below

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source = "integrations/github"
      version = "4.29.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "github" {
  token = "PAT here"

}

resource "github_repository" "byterraform" {
  name        = "byterraform"
  description = "Repo created by terraform script"

  visibility = "private"

  template {
    owner      = "github"
    repository = "terraform-module-template"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you switched providers recently from `hashicorp/github` to `integrations/github`?

Comment: This is a bug in the provider's code for specifying the endpoint.

Comment: I am very new to this and just followed the documentation here. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository

Answer (score 1):

Issue is due to template code i.e.

**Remove below lines from code**

```
  template {
    owner      = "github"
    repository = "terraform-module-template"
  }
```

since this code is trying to refer a template file but is unable to find one since there is none being passed to terraform, hence it gave 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar issue. Solved by:

- Re-generated github token
- used/replaced new token to/in
  `provider "github" { token = "Re-generated github token" }`